# Play framework artefacts only found on second attempt

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, playframework, playframework-2.0, bamboo

I'm setting up a build system for a play project on Atlassian bamboo which runs on AWS. When I do a command such as "play dist" it fails to download core play artefacts:

[error] download failed: com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.3!play_2.10.pom
[error] download failed: com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.3!play_2.10.jar(src)
[error] download failed: com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.10;2.2.3!play-cache_2.10.pom
[error] download failed: com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.10;2.2.3!play-cache_2.10.jar(src)

However, when i run the command a second time straight afterwards it works fine. I am completely baffled as to why this should only work on the second attempt.